# PHP & MySQL does not update database

Tags: php, mysql

could anyone look this code over and tell me why it doesnt update the database?  I know its hacked together, I am a novice at PHP

thanks in advance

```
<?php
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE depot = 'plainview'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Count table rows
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

//update
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

$sql1 = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET 

    available='{$_POST['available'][$i]}', 
    rent='{$_POST['rent'][$i]}', 
    corp_ready='{$_POST['corp_ready'][$i]}', 
    down='{$_POST['down'][$i]}', 
    gfs='{$_POST['gfs'][$i]}',
    dateTime = NOW()  

WHERE id='$id[$i]'"; 


$result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
}
}

//redirect
if($result1){
header("location: plainview.php");
}



mysql_close();
?>
```

======================

## entire code

```
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE depot = 'plainview'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Count table rows
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

//update
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

$sql1 = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET 

available='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['available'][$i])."', 
rent='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rent'][$i])."',  
corp_ready='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['corp_ready'][$i])."', 
down='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['down'][$i])."',  
gfs='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gfs'][$i])."', 
dateTime = NOW()   
WHERE id='".$id[$i]."'";



$result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
}
}

//redirect
if($result1){
header("location: plainview.php");
}




mysql_close();
?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script language="JavaScript1.1" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function mm_jumpmenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
  eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
  if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}
//-->
</script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <p>Plainview, North East Region</p>
    <p>Select a different region: <select onchange="mm_jumpmenu('parent',this,0)" name="lostlist">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Your Depot</option>
                <option value="plainview.php">Plainview</option>
                <option value="worcrester.php">Worcrester</option>

                </select></p>
</div><Br />

<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Product Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Available</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Rent</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Corp Ready</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Down</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>GFS</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td align="left"><?php $id[]=$rows['id']; ?><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>

<td align="left"><?php echo $rows['product']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><input name="available[]" type="text" id="available" value="<?php echo $rows['available']; ?>" size="5"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="rent[]" type="text" id="rent" value="<?php echo $rows['rent']; ?>" size="5"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="corp_ready[]" type="text" id="corp_ready" value="<?php echo $rows['corp_ready']; ?>" size="5"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="down[]" type="text" id="down" value="<?php echo $rows['down']; ?>" size="5" /></td>
<td align="center"><input name="gfs[]" type="text" id="gfs" value="<?php echo $rows['gfs']; ?>" size="5"></td>

</tr>
<?php
}
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
<?php

echo "$sql1";

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does echo $sql1 return and what error message you get? Where do you assign $tbl_name?

Comment: Hello Bobby Tables and insufficient error handling..

Comment: what does `echo mysql_error();` says.

Comment: $tbl_name is set earlier, no issues there

Comment: echo mysqL_error(); gives no error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always escape all user input. Your update query should look like

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET 

available='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['available'][$i])."', 
rent='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rent'][$i])."',  
corp_ready='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['corp_ready'][$i])."', 
down='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['down'][$i])."',  
gfs='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gfs'][$i])."', 
dateTime = NOW()   
WHERE id='".$id[$i]."'";
```

Comment: @Peter: Also, check if a record with id equals `$id[$i]` really exists in your table. If doesn't, nothing changes, and no errors are given.

Answer (score 4):

Try `echo "id='$id[$i]'<br />";` and see if you are getting the ID's that should be sent.

Comment: well thats you prob you can't change a id you don't give

Comment: try changing `WHERE id='$id[$i]'` to `WHERE id='$i'`

Comment: I don't see where you are setting `$id`

Comment: it is now inserting the data but moving it up 1 row in the database, so everything gets moved up

Comment: is `$id` a field in the form if so it would need to be `$_POST['id']`

Comment: I will edit my original post to reflect the entire code so you can get a better idea.

Comment: oops...
`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: you will see that $id is never set you need to set that to some primary key and give it a value for your code to work

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: result1 in plainview.php on line 43

Answer (score 2):

Has `$tbl_name` been set outside of the code you've provided?  If not, set it so your sql knows what table to work with.